# How can I ensure all log statements in Java Config files are outputted?

Tags: spring, logging

I have log statements in Java Spring Config file (@Configuration) that are never being outputted to the log file. I am assuming this is some sort of race issue where logging is not yet enabled while the web app is coming up.

Is there a way to ensure logging is enabled and working so I can see all the log statements?

Comment: What framework are you using for logging? Do you do any configuration?
How do you invoke logger? Can you post relevant code?